# In pymc3, drawing the binomial n parameter from the categorical distribution throws error

Tags: pymc3

To fix things, consider the following simple model:

```
import numpy as np
import pymc3 as pm
#(a few other stuff)

obsv = np.array([12., 45., 64., 34., 57.])
M = 400
with pm.Model() as model:
    p_cat = (1/M)*np.ones(M)
    theta = pm.Beta('rate', 1,1)
    num = pm.Categorical('n', p_cat)

    #likelihood
    resp = pm.Binomial('resp', n=num, p=theta, observed=obsv)
```

Now, if I try to find the MAP, it throws the following error:

> ValueError: Optimization error: max, logp or dlogp at max have non-finite values. Some values may be outside of distribution support. max: {'count': array(0), 'rate_logodds_': array(0.0)}.. etc. etc.

At first glance it seems there is something wrong with sampling from the count variable.

And sure enough, when I run:

```
count.tag.test_value  # -> 0
```

(My libraries are up-to-date. I'm using python3)

Comment: did you solve your problem ?